# Deploying TF 1.0 on GC ML with GPUs queues forever

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm using the following parameters:

- scale_tier = CUSTOM
- master_type = standard_gpu
- worker_count = 0
- ps_count = 0
- runtime_version = 1.0

The logs show the message `Job <job_name> is queued.` without ever printing the next log message I usually see (`Waiting for job to be provisioned.`).  My job has been stuck like this for 30 minutes, and I've tried twice already.

I tried submitting the same job without GPUs (i.e., scale_tier = BASIC), and it moved onto the provisioning stage and eventually finished.

What might be going on?

Comment: Sorry you are having trouble can you please provide a project id and job id so we can investigate? If you don't want to post them publicly you can email them to us privately at cloudml-feedback@google.com.

Comment: I've emailed the project/job id, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this error was because we ran out of quota for GPUs.  When I killed some jobs that were using GPU, the queued job moved forward into the provisioning phase.

Thanks!